# Concatenation of two tables in Javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, concatenation

I have two html tables which I render in my react component and I want to create a third html table which is the concatenation of the first two tables. To be more specific I have a table:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>Collaterals Value</td>
     <td>Buying Power/Available Power</td>
     <td>Market to Market</tr>
     <td>Outstanding Order Margin</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and another table like this:

```
<table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>fdsfdsfds</td>
             <td>fdsfdsfds/td>
             <td>fdsfsdfds</tr>
             <td>fdsfdsfds</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

I want to create a table like

```
<table>
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>Collaterals Value</td>
     <td>Buying Power/Available Power</td>
     <td>Market to Market</tr>
     <td>Outstanding Order Margin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>fdsfdsfds</td>
     <td>fdsfdsfds/td>
     <td>fdsfsdfds</tr>
     <td>fdsfdsfds</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas of how I can  implement this?

Comment: I think maybe you accidentally but your code blocks out of order-- middle table looks like a concatenation of the first and last table.

Comment: Concatenation means adding/combining etc.. Your post title doesn't match the example. Do you want to eliminate (remove or ignore) common data and create a table with different data from both tables

Comment: @anied You might be right. or OP got confused with word Concatenation

Comment: Just write another model (reducer if you use react/redux) and have it operate on the joining of the data. Don't touch the rendered tables.

Comment: No i dont want to eliminate the data, just want to create a union

Comment: @shilly why shouldnt he touch the tables? he's asking something and you just say don't do something without a nice explanation :D

Comment: Actually now that I really read this, if it's a react component, are you generating these tables out of data?? If so, combine the two arrays of data and then create a 3rd table.

Comment: @MarcelD I tried to say what Andrew just said. If it's a react component, you just write another reducer that changes the data behind the tables and rerender the table again, since in react/redux the models are the single source of truth. Any solution that relies on manipulating the tables directly by selecting them from the DOM and pretending the table itsself is the data structure, misses the point of using react to create your views. I assumed that someone who uses react would understand what I mean with writing another reducer to manipulate the same data that made the tables.

Comment: I maybe wrongly assume he also uses redux or another flux implementation to create the models.

Comment: @Shilly thats what i wanted to read before: don't do it ;)

Comment: Why are you in the topic anyway? Where's your solution or advice?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is get the append the tr from the second table to the tbody of the first table.  Javascript will take care of doing the removal from the second table as a part of the appendChild.

```js
  var tables = document.querySelectorAll("tbody");
  tables[0].appendChild(tables[1].querySelector("tr"));
```

```html
Table 1
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>Collaterals Value</td>
     <td>Buying Power/Available Power</td>
     <td>Market to Market</tr>
     <td>Outstanding Order Margin</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Table 2
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>fdsfdsfds</td>
         <td>fdsfdsfds</td>
         <td>fdsfsdfds</td>
         <td>fdsfdsfds</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice answer but i dont want to have a button. Just want this tables to rendered as a union. Thanks anyway

Comment: I added the button so that you could see it work in real time.  The code inside the click function is what does the work.  Just use this part in your code.   var tables = document.querySelectorAll("tbody");
  tables[0].appendChild(tables[1].querySelector("tr"));

Comment: Button removed.